# find density function of sum of two independent exponential distribution

Tags: probability

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent exponential random variables, both with mean $\beta$, find the density function for their sum.

My attempt:

Let $F_U(u)=P(X_1+X_2 \leq u)=\int_o^u\int_0^{u-x_2}\beta e^{-\beta x_1}\beta e^{\beta x_2}dx_1dx_2 = -e^{-\beta u}-\beta u e^{-\beta u}+1$.

so the density is $F'(u)=(u+1)e^{-\beta u}$.

But the solution says that it is not correct.

Comment: **NB** If the mean of an exponential distribution is $\beta$, then the density function is $$f_X(x)=\tfrac 1\beta e^{-x/\beta}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F'(u) = \beta e^{-\beta u} - \beta e^{- \beta u} +(-\beta)(-\beta u e^{-\beta u})= \beta^2 u e^{-\beta u}$$

Notice that I have used product rule for the second term.

A name for the sum of IID exponential distribution is known as Erlang distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Try building the probability of $X_1$ first taken $X_2$ as given, an idea could be

$$\gamma(X_2)=Pr(X_1+X_2\le u|X_2),$$

then note that the cdf you are looking for is $F(x)=Pr(\gamma(X_2) \le x) = Pr(\gamma^{-1}(x) \le X_2) $.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your integral. You have a wrong sign in the second exponent. If you correct it and redo the integral you will get a result $f(u) = \beta^2 u e^{- \beta u} $

Answer (score 1):

Since you only wish to find the probability *density* function, you can save some effort.

$$\begin{align}f_U(u) &=\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant u}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d u}\int_0^u\int_0^{u-x} f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x \\[1ex] &= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant u}\cdot\int_0^u f_{X_1}(x)\,f_{X_2}(u-x) \,\mathrm d x\\[1ex] &=\tfrac 1{\beta^2}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant u}\cdot\int_0^u \mathrm e^{-x/\beta}\,\mathrm e^{-(u-x)/\beta}\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\tfrac u{\beta^2}\,\mathrm e^{-u/\beta}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant u}\end{align}$$

---

**PS:** When the mean of an exponential distribution is $\beta$ then the pdf is $f_X(x)=\tfrac 1\beta\,\mathrm e^{-x/\beta}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}$